# How to increment a value in HTML every time a selenium test case is ran

Tags: html, selenium

I am testing a registration page for a website, I am a beginner in HTML scrip. I am struggling to automate the script to register as there is validation on the email address to be unique. Can anyone tell me how to increment a value in the code below.

```
<tr>
<td>type</td>
<td>id=MainContent_Email</td>
<td>validtestemail@test.com</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use selenium-webdriver to execute a script that can change the text of one of the cells.

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("var cellValue = $('td1').text(); cellValue = cellValue + 1; $('td2').text(cellValue)");
```

Something similar to that javascript in the above example.

Another way is to format a string within the Selenium running code and increment that way:

```
string scriptToRun = string.Format("var cellValue = {0}; cellValue = cellValue + 1; $('td2').text(cellValue)", incrementingValue);
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(scriptToRun);
```

The script selectors above need to be improved and match your html.